# count posts from custom taxonomy terms by year

Tags: wp-query, count

I want to build statistics-like tables with the count of posts in given custom taxonomy terms and display them by year along with the total post count from that year.

For example:

> **2014**
>
> |_Taxonomy Term A: 8 posts
>
> |_ Taxonomy Term B: 12 posts
>
> **Total posts in 2014:** 20 posts

The function obviously needs to do the following:

- count posts from my-custom-post-type that have been published in 2014, 2013, ... (total count per year)
- count the posts in each taxonomy term from my-custom-taxonomy on the yearly base

To make a **dynamic list for the years**, I used a snippet I found somewhere and it looks like this:

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);
  return $years;
}
```

In my custom page template, I use:

```
<?php foreach(posts_by_year() as $year => $posts) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $year; ?></h2>
// the code that I need to display the post counts per year
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**My question is:**

How do I build the wp_query to be able to output the post count per taxonomy term per year?
I'd be so glad if anyone helped me sort that out.

PS: 
I already have a table counting ALL published posts from my-custom-post-type per taxonomy term, I found help [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154771/calculate-percentage-of-post-by-category) and used deflime's code.

**Edit:**

This is Pieter Goosen's snippet including my modifications:

```
$oldest = get_posts( 'post_type=my-custom-post-type&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC' );
$oldest_date = $oldest[0]->post_date;

$first_date = date('Y', strtotime($oldest_date));
$todays_date = date('Y');

$year_range = range($todays_date, $first_date);

foreach ($year_range as $year) { // dynamic year-based tables
    echo '<h2>' . $year . '</h2>';
    $terms = get_terms('my-custom-taxonomy');
    $total_posts = 0;

    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { // table body

        echo '
            <table class="statistics">
            <tbody>
            ';
        echo '
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Taxonomy Term</td>
                    <td>Percentage</td>
                    <td class="chart-count">Count</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            ';
        echo '
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Posts total</td>
                <td class="chart-count">'.$total_posts.'</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            ';

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { // setup table <tr> per taxonomy term
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'         => 'my-custom-post-type',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'year'              => $year,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'my-custom-taxonomy',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term->slug
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $total_posts += $term->count;
            // Get  %, round to 2 decimal places
            $percentage = round( (($yearly_posts_per_term->post_count / $total_posts)*100), 2 );
            // will add up to 100 at the end?
            $total_check += $percentage;

            $yearly_posts_per_term = new WP_Query($args);

            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td class="chart-item">'.$term->name.'</td>
                    <td class="chart-visual"><div class="chart-bar" style="width:'.$percentage.'%;"></div> '.$percentage.'%</td>
                    <td class="chart-count">'.$yearly_posts_per_term->post_count.'</td>
                </tr>
            ';

        } // endforeach
        echo '
            </tbody>
            </table>
            '; 
    } //end of table
} // end of year-based list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Here is another version of the code in *EDIT 1*. This code is about much more faster. Here is my test between the code in *EDIT 1* and *EDIT 2*

- *EDIT 1* Database query time = +/- 0.25 and Database queries = 69
- *EDIT 2* Database query time = +/- 0.07 and Database queries = 29

Here is the code

```
<?php

 $oldest = get_posts( 'post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC' );
    $oldest_date = $oldest[0]->post_date;

    $first_date = date('Y', strtotime($oldest_date));
    $todays_date = date('Y');

    $year_range = range($todays_date, $first_date);

    foreach ($year_range as $year) { // dynamic year-based tables
        echo '<h2>' . $year . '</h2>';
        $terms = get_terms('category');

        $term_slugs = array();

        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { // table body

            foreach ( $terms as $key=>$term){
                $term_slugs[$key] = $term->slug;
            }

            echo '
                <table class="statistics">
                <tbody>
                ';
            echo '
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Taxonomy Term</td>
                        <td>Percentage</td>
                        <td class="chart-count">Count</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                ';

            $posts_count = array(); // Holds all term post counts in an array
            $terms_array = array();  // Holds all term names in an array 

                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                    'post_type'         => 'post',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'year'              => $year,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'          => 'category',
                            'field'             => 'slug',
                            'terms'             => $term_slugs,
                            'include_children'  => false 
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $yearly_posts_per_term = new WP_Query($args);
                    $posts_count[] = $yearly_posts_per_term->post_count; //Collects post counts and send them to an array

                if($yearly_posts_per_term->have_posts()):
                    while($yearly_posts_per_term->have_posts()): $yearly_posts_per_term->the_post();

                        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );

                        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $terms_array[] = $term->slug;
                            }
                        } 

                    endwhile;
                endif;

        }

        $total_posts = array_sum($posts_count); //Use array_sum to add up all the separate post counts

        $result = array_count_values($terms_array);

        foreach ($result as $term_name=>$count) {

            $percentage = round( (($count / $total_posts)*100), 2 ); //Calculate the percentages of each term post cound to total year post count

            echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart-item">'.$term_name.'</td>
                        <td class="chart-visual"><div class="chart-bar" style="width:'.$percentage.'%;"></div> '.$percentage.'%</td>
                        <td class="chart-count">'.$count.'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';
        }   

            echo '
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Posts total</td>
                    <td class="chart-count">'.$total_posts.'</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                ';

            echo '
                </tbody>
                </table>
                '; 
    } // end of year-based list

?>
```

This renders the same output as the table in *EDIT 1*, except, it does not show empty terms, only terms with posts are shown

[image]

**EDIT 1**

From your edited question, here is the strip down of the new code. I had to scrap one or two things here and rearrange some elements to make this work. The big challenge here was to calculate the percentages, because the variables that is used to calculate this lived in separate `foreach` loops. Variables within `foreach` loops only lives within that `foreach`, not outsie

The big changes to the code (from my original answer, @deflime code and your integrated code) from your edit are

- Moved the two tables holding the total posts count and the percentages and term names to outside just below the `$terms` `foreach` loop
- Pushed the term names and posts count from each term to an array outside the `$terms` `foreach` loop
- Scrapped @deflime code, removed `$total_posts = 0;` and only kept and modified `$percentage = round( (($yearly_posts_per_term->post_count / $total_posts)*100), 2 );`
- Used [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to get the total amount of posts for the year from the array of post counts per term
- Used [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create an associative array with the term names and post counts from each term
- Finally, I used a `foreach` loop to get each term name and the associated post count, to feed that back into the table

Here is the final code

```
<?php

 $oldest = get_posts( 'post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC' );
    $oldest_date = $oldest[0]->post_date;

    $first_date = date('Y', strtotime($oldest_date));
    $todays_date = date('Y');

    $year_range = range($todays_date, $first_date);

    foreach ($year_range as $year) { // dynamic year-based tables
        echo '<h2>' . $year . '</h2>';
        $terms = get_terms('category');

        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { // table body

            echo '
                <table class="statistics">
                <tbody>
                ';
            echo '
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Taxonomy Term</td>
                        <td>Percentage</td>
                        <td class="chart-count">Count</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                ';

            $posts_count = array(); // Holds all term post counts in an array
            $term_names = array();  // Holds all term names in an array

            foreach($terms as $term) {
                $term_names[] = $term->name; //Collects term names and send them to an array

                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                    'post_type'         => 'post',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'year'              => $year,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'          => 'category',
                            'field'             => 'slug',
                            'terms'             => $term->slug,
                            'include_children'  => false 
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $yearly_posts_per_term = new WP_Query($args);
                    $posts_count[] = $yearly_posts_per_term->post_count; //Collects post counts and send them to an array

            } // endforeach

            unset($term);

        }

        $total_posts = array_sum($posts_count); //Use array_sum to add up all the separate post counts

        $combine = array_combine($term_names,$posts_count); //Use array_combine to combine term names and post counts into assosiative array

        foreach ($combine as $term_name=>$count) {

            $percentage = round( (($count / $total_posts)*100), 2 ); //Calculate the percentages of each term post cound to total year post count

            echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart-item">'.$term_name.'</td>
                        <td class="chart-visual"><div class="chart-bar" style="width:'.$percentage.'%;"></div> '.$percentage.'%</td>
                        <td class="chart-count">'.$count.'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';
        }   

            echo '
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Posts total</td>
                    <td class="chart-count">'.$total_posts.'</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                ';

            echo '
                </tbody>
                </table>
                '; 
    } // end of year-based list

?>
```

*Please note* As in my original answer, I've changed the post type to `post` and taxonomy to `category` for the purpose of testing.

Your end result is a table looking like this. *Please note* All my term names are in Afrikaans as I tested it on my test site that is in Afrikaans.

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This is a very rough draft of an idea I had on how to do this. I've included no HTML mark-up and used the default post type `post` and the build-in taxonomy `category` to test the code.

Here is how I constructed the complete query

- First, get the date of the oldest post (should be the first post) on the site. This is done by a simple [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) query. Modify to suite your needs

  ```
  $oldest = get_posts( 'post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC' );
      $oldest_date = $oldest[0]->post_date;
  ```
- Next, strip the returned date to only get the year from the post date. Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert the year into a Unix timestamp

  ```
  $first_date = date('Y', strtotime($oldest_date));
  ```
- Return the current date, you would want only the year. Use the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

  ```
  $current_date = date('Y');
  ```
- Return both dates to the [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function to print a range of years between the two dates

  ```
  $year_range = range($current_date, $first_date);
  ```
- Add these ranges back into a `foreach loop` to get your posts in year based lists
- I've used [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to geta list of all the available terms  of the taxonomy in question

  ```
  $terms = get_terms('category');
  ```
- Now, all of this info needs to be fed back into a `tax_query` using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

  ```
  $args = array(
          'posts_per_page'    => -1,
          'post_type'         => 'post',
          'post_status'       => 'publish',
          'year'              => $year,
          'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => $term->slug
              ),
          ),
      );

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
  ```
- Lastly, you want to return the term name and the amount of posts per term

  ```
  echo $term->name . '(' . $posts->post_count . ')';
  ```

Now all together!!

```
<?php
$oldest = get_posts( 'post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC' );
    $oldest_date = $oldest[0]->post_date;

$first_date = date('Y', strtotime($oldest_date));
$current_date = date('Y');

$year_range = range($current_date, $first_date);

foreach ($year_range as $year) {
    echo $year;

    $terms = get_terms('category');
    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'year'              => $year,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term->slug
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                echo $term->name . '(' . $posts->post_count . ')';
        }
    }
}
 ?>
```

As said, this can be refined, so take this idea and code and adapt and modify as you see fit. Hope this helps.

Comment: you, sir, are my hero of the month! I modified this glorious snippet to fit my custom-post-type-needs. Dang, that's cool! There is just one last question: I want to display those information in a table in order to build statistics. Before, I had a code that calculated percentages for each taxonomy term. I think I must have displaced the variables and such, could you please review my customized snippet? I'll post it in my question above if you don't mind.

Comment: Good Morning, I'm still busy working on this problem. I just got to work, so I can only continue again tonight. I got most sorted out, had to rearrange code and scrap the code from @deflime Only one thing still bugs me, that is calculating the percentage. Maths around that is easy, the problem is, none of the variables lives in the same foreach loops (a variable inside a foreach loop only lives in that loop, and not outside), so I'm trying to work around that.

Comment: Pieter, thank you very much. I tried to rearrange the variables by myself but, as you see, I didn't find a solution that outputs the correct value. I know this isn't as easy as it sounds, I am grateful for you helping me sorting it out. Take your time, in the meantime I'll be working on it, too.

Comment: Pieter, you're a genius, I'd even buy you a beer (or three). Your code works like a charm, this case is so closed :D

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out for you. Enjoy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler solution than the one you accepted, using just one single query. I illustrate here for the custom post type 'product' and the custom taxonomy 'product_cat'(egory) in Woocommerce, just because I happen to have a handy install to test it. The `$query` is:

```
SELECT YEAR(p.post_date), t.name, COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(p.ID), GROUP_CONCAT(p.post_title)
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status='publish'
GROUP BY YEAR(p.post_date), tt.term_taxonomy_id
ORDER by YEAR(p.post_date) DESC, tt.term_taxonomy_id ASC
```

In my sample install, this yields:

[image: taxonomy stats per year]

So for example there are 10 posts of Clothing in 2013 and 2 in 2012.

You just need to call `$wpdb->get_results($query)` (and use $wpdb->prefix instead of 'wp_') to get this table into an array or object, calculate the percentages, and display them. The group_concat columns are added mostly for debugging (thus you probably want to remove them), though on the other hand the id's, for example, may also come handy for other processing (by exploding values in the column into arrays).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a more easier shorter code to display only specific year instead of running a loop to display all the years from the post. This is the code [image].

This also includes link to the taxonomy term archive.
`

```
    $terms = get_terms('your-taxonomy'); //grab the taxonomy name
    $year  = 2015; // The year you want to pull the terms and count from

    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){ 
    echo '<div class="barometer">'; //class to apply css if you want
        echo '<ul>'; 

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
                $args = array(
            //'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'post', // disable this line if you want to grap from all post types
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'year'              => $year,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term->slug
                    ),
                ),
            );

            $post_year = new WP_Query($args); 

                $term = sanitize_term( $term, 'your-taxonomy' ); 
                $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'your-taxonomy' ); //Get the links to the term archive page

        // If the term has no post, it does not display. You can remove the if statement from here if you want to display empty terms   
        if ($post_year->post_count > 0 ) {

            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) .'" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all %s stories','media-foundation' ), $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '<span>' .$post_year->post_count. '</span>' . '</a></li>'; 

        } // End of if $post_year->post_count

    } // End of Foreach term loop
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';          
}
```

`